# Append two hibernate query list and store in third query list

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

The first table contain list from Database and store in `qry` and the second     table also contain list from Database and store in `qry1` then how to append these     list in the third `qry2`.

```
Query qry = getSession().createQuery("select * from table1");
Query qry1 = getSession().createQuery("select * from table2");
Query qry2 = dry+qry1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simple do

```
List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
result.addAll(qry.list());
result.addAll(qry1.list());
```

You have to take a List of Object's since the both Pojo's are different from `table1` to `table2`.